# How to send data using tcpclient on button click event as many times as i want without reestablishing connection?

Tags: c#, connection, tcpclient

I have c# server-client app..client sends its two ids to server.It works fine one time.But if the same client want to send another request..it does not work.
Because if i remove 'tcpclient.close' command,my server execution suspends.
Here is code..

**Server:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
namespace newserver
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Socket sck;
        // EndPoint epLocal, epRemote;
        IPAddress ipAdress;
        TcpListener myList;
        string serverIP;
        private PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
        int cpuLoad;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitialiseCPUCounter();
            timer1.Start();
            serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
        }
        private string GetLocalIP()
        {
            IPHostEntry host;
            host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return ip.ToString();
                }
            }
            return "127.0.0.1";
        }
        private void InitialiseCPUCounter()
        {
            cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter(
            "Processor",
            "% Processor Time",
            "_Total",
            true
            );
        }
        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            ipAdress = IPAddress.Parse(serverIP);
            myList = new TcpListener(ipAdress, Convert.ToInt32("8000"));
            myList.Start();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[2560];
            string data = "";
            //sck = myList.AcceptSocket();
            TcpClient client = myList.AcceptTcpClient();
            btnStart.Text = "Connected";
            lblCAFrom.Visible = true;
            IPEndPoint ipep = (IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
            IPAddress ipa = ipep.Address;
            txtCIP.Text = ipa.ToString();
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            int i;

            i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            while (i != 0)
            {
                // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            string[] arr = data.Split(new char[] { ';' });
            int length = arr.Length;
            int no_of_req = length / 2;
            // ..............server register....................//
            string constr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Ayne\Documents\db.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();
            int j = 0;
            while (j < no_of_req)
            {
                string insert_register = "INSERT INTO Register(IP,IMPU,IMPI) Values('" + ipa.ToString() + "','" + arr[0] + "','" + arr[1] + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert_register, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                j++;
            }


            con.Close();



            txtCIP.Visible = true;
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cpuLoad = Convert.ToInt32(cpuCounter.NextValue());
            this.txtCPUusage.Text =
     cpuLoad.ToString() +
     "%";
        }
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
namespace newserver
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Socket sck;
        // EndPoint epLocal, epRemote;
        IPAddress ipAdress;
        TcpListener myList;
        string serverIP;
        private PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
        int cpuLoad;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitialiseCPUCounter();
            timer1.Start();
            serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
        }
        private string GetLocalIP()
        {
            IPHostEntry host;
            host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return ip.ToString();
                }
            }
            return "127.0.0.1";
        }
        private void InitialiseCPUCounter()
        {
            cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter(
            "Processor",
            "% Processor Time",
            "_Total",
            true
            );
        }
        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            ipAdress = IPAddress.Parse(serverIP);
            myList = new TcpListener(ipAdress, Convert.ToInt32("8000"));
            myList.Start();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[2560];
            string data = "";
            //sck = myList.AcceptSocket();
            TcpClient client = myList.AcceptTcpClient();
            btnStart.Text = "Connected";
            lblCAFrom.Visible = true;
            IPEndPoint ipep = (IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
            IPAddress ipa = ipep.Address;
            txtCIP.Text = ipa.ToString();
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            int i;

            i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            while (i != 0)
            {
                // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            string[] arr = data.Split(new char[] { ';' });
            int length = arr.Length;
            int no_of_req = length / 2;
            // ..............server register....................//
            string constr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Ayne\Documents\db.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();
            int j = 0;
            while (j < no_of_req)
            {
                string insert_register = "INSERT INTO Register(IP,IMPU,IMPI) Values('" + ipa.ToString() + "','" + arr[0] + "','" + arr[1] + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert_register, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                j++;
            }


            con.Close();



            txtCIP.Visible = true;
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cpuLoad = Convert.ToInt32(cpuCounter.NextValue());
            this.txtCPUusage.Text =
     cpuLoad.ToString() +
     "%";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was asking myself this very question today ,
I came Across a YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgLRe7QV6QI&list=WL&index=9) that explains it nicely.

It should not be too hard to convert this code to a form application.

The Main Trick Seems to be to multi-thread the incoming connections
And Use [asynchronous socket](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/379cca53-9920-4167-bd51-d685b25ac0dc/questions-about-tcpclient-tcplistener-and-socket-classes?forum=ncl) rather than TcpListener(TcpListener may be easier how ever)

I hope This Helps

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this is like asking a politician to explain why they need to send so much of our money to foreign countries. To ask for a "simple" answer would only garner a nasty look and a cold shoulder.  Nice try, I suppose that somewhere in there is an answer, but it beats me.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: Please only post an answer to a question if you intend to help finding a solution to the problem. Answers are not mean to be comments and there is a reason why new users need to earn the privilege to comment